# why a-animation don't work on A-Frame 1.1.0? it works on version 0.8.0

Tags: aframe

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity>
    <a-entity position="2 2 -10" geometry="primitive: sphere" material="color: red"></a-entity>
    <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="10000" fill="forwards" to="0 360 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

when I change 1.1.0 to 0.8.0, the a-animation works, tell me why

Answer (score 0):

`<a-animation>` has been deprecated in favor of the [animation component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/animation.html#sidebar):

```
 <a-box position="-1 1.6 -5" animation="property: position; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; loop: true" color="tomato"></a-box>
```

Comment: thanks，what I see is the document before: https://www.techbrood.com/aframe/core?p=animations

Comment: I recommend checking the [official site](https://aframe.io/docs) for updated documentation. If you ca mark the answer as correct it will be greatly appreciated.